# Android: Is there a way to update the UI for an Activity while Keyboard is active?

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, animation

It seems that when my keyboard is active, it waits to update my UI until keyboard is dismissed.

I have a RecyclerView that will update its contents based on my search in the AutoCompleteTextView.

What I would like is for the UI to update during my keyboard presses, not after I have dismissed the keyboard.

Any ideas? Am I running on the wrong thread maybe?

Comment: Have a look at TextView.OnEditorActionListener - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add a Text Change listener to your EditText, so you can do something (update UI/whatever) with the data that the user enter.

```
mMyEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) 
    {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
       //do something

    }
);
```